# No able to download system.log through FTP connection

Tags: magento-1.9, log, debug, ftp

I open files of a site in Magento 1.9 through Notepad++ with plugin for FTP connection. I don't try to download system.log file.
The error is the following:

```
Download of /balmain/var/log/system.log failed
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Magento log files can get very large. Up to 300 MB or higher if they're not cleaned up. The extension for Notepad++ FTP you are using may have problems with large text files like this.

I use Brackets often, and wasn't able to open a log file because it was over the maximum file size. I was able to open this large .log file in Notepad++ and Notepad though. This is why I think the FTP extension is at fault.

I highly recommend downloading the log file to your desktop via FTP, and then opening in Notepad++ from your desktop. Filezilla is a good free FTP program that's easy to set up, if you don't already have one.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but using Filezilla and attempting to download file the result is always the same..